# R: parameter in update function

Tags: r

Here is a snippet of R script doing beta regression on data "GasolineYield":

```
library("betareg")
data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")
gy_logit <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)
gy_logit4 <- update(gy_logit, subset = -4)
```

The 4th line magically deletes the 4th observation and update the fit automatically, but I don't quite understand the why this parameter works in the update function here, because I tried to look up the documentation by `?update`, but couldn't find there's such parameter.

I'm curious about how to find right documentation in this case, because maybe I want to add some new observation instead of removing it. Any help?

Comment: Usually a negative subset removes that column and leaves the rest.   Like an inverse subset.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make my question clear, I wanted to know why there isn't such parameter in the documentation, I've edited it.

Comment: You're having trouble finding it because `subset` is part of the  `... further arguments passed to or from other methods.` list.  It looks like this function is changing the formula in the line above it

Comment: Then where can I find what's the original documentation where the parameter `subset` is explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset` in `betareg` works the same as `subset` in `lm`, therefore you can read `lm` documentation.

From the help file you can find:

> `subset` an optional vector specifying a subset of observations to be used in the fitting process.

Hence by setting `select=-4` you are lefting out the fourth row in the estimation.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make my question clear, I wanted to know why there isn't such parameter in the documentation while it still works. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

`update()` contains the `...` parameter, which means any parameters that are not matched in your call to `update()` are passed on to the function that does the estimation.  In this case, that is `betareg()`, which does have the `subset` argument.

This type of thing is very common in R.  Many higher-level function that call other user-visible functions will have the three dot parameter and pass any unmatched parameters on, so you have to search all the user-visible functions that get called in order to know all possible options.

You can check out the help file for the top level function (`update()` in this case) to get an idea of which functions get the leftover parameters.